# ParentController.apply() Not Working Inside ChildController Because Of IIFEs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iife

When the IIFE is removed from ParentController in the following snippet, ParentController.apply() works as expected within ChildController.

However, when ParentController is inside an IIFE, ParentController.apply() does not work within ChildController because ParentController is undefined.

I know that this is because the IIFE around ParentController is removing it from the global scope. My question is: How do I keep the IIFEs around both ParentController and ChildController while still having ParentController.apply() work properly (i.e. - not error out as 'undefined')?

**NOTE: I do not want to use $scope in my solution, so don't suggest anything having to do with $scope when answering. Also, ParentController and ChildController are in separate files, so putting them both in the same IIFE is not a valid solution.**

```js
angular.module('app', []);

(function () {

  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('ParentController', ParentController);

  function ParentController() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.hello = "Hello from Parent Controller!";
    vm.helloAgain = function() {
      return "Hello again from Parent Controller";
    }
  }
})();

(function () {

  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('ChildController', ChildController);

  function ChildController() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.hello = "Hello from Child Controller!";
    
    ParentController.apply();

    vm.helloAgain = function() {
      return parent.helloAgain();
    }
  }
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="ParentController as parent">
      <h4>{{ parent.hello }}</h4>
      <div ng-controller="ChildController as child">
        <h4>{{ child.hello }}</h4>
        <h4>{{ parent.hello }}</h4>
    
        <!-- calls parent.helloAgain() from app.childController.js -->
        <h1>{{ child.helloAgain() }}</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: What you're asking for doesn't make too much sense, but is `angular` a global variable via which you can access `ParentController` from the `ChildController` file, e.g. `angular.module('app').controller('ParentController')` perhaps?

Comment: What I am asking for totally makes sense. I am attempting to access a ParentController method inside of ChildController.  The IIFE around ParentController is hiding it from ChildController. I want to find a way to keep the IIFE but still expose ParentController to ChildController. Thanks for your suggestion, but it won't solve the issue for me.

Comment: No, it doesn't. The point of those IIFEs is to scope the variables / functions so they're NOT accessible from outside. So if you're declaring variables inside the IIFE you need some other mechanism to make them accessible to each other. Elaborate on why my suggestion won't solve the issue.

Comment: What I am asking for does not make sense to you. I know what the point of an IIFE is. A angular parent controller cannot be accessed in the way you are suggesting, which is why I said your suggestion would not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably pretty hokey, but it seems like what you're asking for:

```js
angular.module('app', []);

(function () {

  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('ParentController', ParentController);

  function ParentController() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.hello = "Hello from Parent Controller!";
    vm.helloAgain = function() {
      return "Hello again from Parent Controller";
    }
    vm.helloYetAgain = function() {
      return "Hello AGAIN from Parent Controller";
    }
  }
})();


(function () {

  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('ChildController', ['$controller', ChildController]);

  function ChildController ($controller) {
    var vm = this;
    var parent = $controller('ParentController');

    parent.constructor.apply(this, arguments);

    vm.hello = "Hello from Child Controller!";

    vm.helloAgain = function() {
      return parent.helloAgain.call(this);
    }
  }
})();
```

```html
<body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="ParentController as parent">
      <h4>{{ parent.hello }}</h4>
      <div ng-controller="ChildController as child">
        <h4>{{ child.hello }}</h4>
        <h4>{{ parent.hello }}</h4>

        <!-- calls parent.helloAgain() from app.childController.js -->
        <h1>{{ child.helloAgain() }}</h1>
        <h1>{{ child.helloYetAgain() }}</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Note that it is not real prototypal inheritance.

Comment: This answer is useful as it does solve the issue I was having. I had tried injecting $controller before, but had the "parent.constructor.apply(this, arguments);" part wrong.  NOTE: calling "return parent.helloAgain.call(this)" from the ChildController helloAgain function does not work for me, but calling "return parent.helloAgain();" from the same function does work. (using real prototypal inheritance would be nice though...) Thanks for your help and your answer!

Comment: @trevor That's odd -- `return parent.helloAgain.call(this)` does work for me. What happens for you -- no output? Error? Prototypal inheritance might be possible with a bit more elaborate setup where you pass a different function to `.controller()` that sets `ChildController.prototype = parent.constructor.prototype` and returns an instance of `ChildController`.

Comment: Whoops, my mistake. I had "return parent.helloAgain().call(this)" instead of "return parent.helloAgain.call(this)".

Comment: Oh ok, that explains it.